# javascript xcode readability

Tags: javascript, xcode, uiwebview

I am trying to use the same system to convert a page with readability bookmarklet as Safari does.

I tried the following:

```
NSString *searchURL = @"javascript:(%28function%28%29%7Bwindow.baseUrl%3D%27https%3A//www.readability.com%27%3Bwindow.readabilityToken%3D%27%27%3Bvar%20s%3Ddocument.createElement%28%27script%27%29%3Bs.setAttribute%28%27type%27%2C%27text/javascript%27%29%3Bs.setAttribute%28%27charset%27%2C%27UTF-8%27%29%3Bs.setAttribute%28%27src%27%2CbaseUrl%2B%27/bookmarklet/read.js%27%29%3Bdocument.documentElement.appendChild%28s%29%3B%7D%29%28%29)";

NSURL *url =  [NSURL URLWithString:[searchURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSLog(@"launched readability");


// NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:searchURL];
[webBrowser loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

but that did not work..

I also tried the following:

```
[webBrowser stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"function%28%29%7Bwindow.baseUrl%3D%27https%3A//www.readability.com%27%3Bwindow.readabilityToken%3D%27%27%3Bvar%20s%3Ddocument.createElement%28%27script%27%29%3Bs.setAttribute%28%27type%27%2C%27text/javascript%27%29%3Bs.setAttribute%28%27charset%27%2C%27UTF-8%27%29%3Bs.setAttribute%28%27src%27%2CbaseUrl%2B%27/bookmarklet/read.js%27%29%3Bdocument.documentElement.appendChild%28s%29%3B%7D%29%28%29"];
```

but that did not work either. Could someone point me in the right direction?

link to readability bookmarklet site:  https://www.readability.com/bookmarklets

Comment: @Casey: Perhaps this should be an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Right, sorry, I hadn't intended my comment to be as long as it came out to be!

Comment: I'm fairly new to javascript and xcode. Could you please be more specific as to were to place the code? I tried both ways with your code but was not successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unescape the JavaScript (i.e., run it through JavaScript's unescape function). So instead of what you have there, use: `(function(){window.baseUrl='https://www.readability.com';window.readabilityToke‌​n='';var s=document.createElement('script');s.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');s.se‌​tAttribute('charset','UTF-8');s.setAttribute('src',baseUrl+'/bookmarklet/read.js');document.documentElemen‌​t.appendChild(s);})()`

Comment: I tried this with no avail: `NSString *searchURL = @"(function(){window.baseUrl='https://www.readability.com';window.readabilityToke‌​n='';var s=document.createElement('script');s.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');s.se‌​tAttribute('charset','UTF-8');s.setAttribute('src',baseUrl+'/bookmarklet/read.js');document.documentElemen‌​t.appendChild(s);})()";
    NSURL *url =  [NSURL URLWithString:[searchURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [webBrowser loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];`